# What is the most efficient strategy to compute the area of the following region? $y=x^2-16$, $3y-16x=0$, $y=0$ for $y \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Please keep in mind, I have included the original question as an image, for any references. So here is what I know: I know I am supposed to set the two equations equal to each other, and then integrate. But for the second equation, $3y-16x-16=0$ am I supposed to solve for $y$, and then set it equal to the first equation? If so, I get some weird numbers, and I am not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this. I know I integrate eventually. Also, what do I do with the $y=0$? Is that for the integration part?

Also, I'm new here, so I apologize in advance for any misconceptions I have, or for any formatting issues. Please notify me of any issues before choosing to downvote me.

Comment: What do you mean by weird numbers? Just equate the $y$ from both the equations and solve the quadratic in $x$. Also $y=0$ refers to the $x$ axis and $y \geq 0$ means you have to work in the first and second quadrants.

Comment: A [sketch](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7By%3Dx%5E2-16,3y-16x-16%3D0,y%3D0%7D) is always a good start and to make a good sketch, find the points of intersection - you'll need those to set up the correct limits anyway.

Comment: The title omits the word area and a constant term in the line equation $3y-16x-16=0$.  It isn't necessary to put everything in the title  (that's what the body of the Question is for), but it is good to avoid misleading.  Would you like me to try editing it?

Comment: So should it look like:  (16*(x+1))/3=x^2-16  ? Then solve for x?

Comment: Thank you guys for your edits!

Comment: Edit as much as you like

Answer (score 0):

You have been supplied 3 curves.

You should plot the 3 curves.  And you should algebraically find the points of intersection of the curves.

Then based on the shape of the curve, make a decision of whether it will be easier to integrate with respect to x or with respect to y.  Which curve will make your upper bound, your lower bound, and what will be your interval to integrate.

Finally you will integrate the result.

$y = x^2 - 16$ is a parabola.
$3y-16 x -16 = 0$ is a line
$y = 0$ is also a line.

$y = 0$ intercepts $y = x^2 - 16$ at $(-4,0),(4,0)$

$3y-16 x-16 = 0$ intercepts $y=0$ at (-1,0).

$y = x^2 - 16$ intercepts $3y-16 x -16= 0$

$y = \frac {16}{3} (x+1)\\
\frac {16}{3} (x+1) = x^2 - 16\\
x^2 - \frac {16}3 x - \frac {64}{3} = 0\\
x = \frac 83 + \frac {\sqrt {64+9\cdot 64}}{3} = \frac {8 + 8\sqrt {10}}{3}\\
y = \frac {176 + 128\sqrt {10}}{9}$

We only care about one of the points of intersection as $y<0$ at the other.

The region is vaguely triangular.  If you integrate with respect to x, you are going to need to break the region in two, if you integrate with respect to y, you do not.

$\int_0^{\frac {176 + 128\sqrt {10}}{9}} \sqrt {y+16} - \frac {3}{16} y + 1 \ dy$

or

$\int_1^4 \frac {16}{3} (x+1)\ dx + \int_4^{\frac {8 +8 \sqrt{10}}{3}} \frac {16}{3}(x+1) - (x^2 - 16)\ dx$

Comment: The given line is $3y-16x-16=0$

Comment: @prog_SAHIL I saw that the problem in the image was not the problem that the OP had posted in the title, and have revised.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, what do I do with the $y=0$? Is that for the integration part?

This is simply the $x$-axis, it's a line and it is one of the graphs that bounds the region in question. The other two graphs are:

- $y=x^2-16$, which is a parabola;
- $3y-16x-16=0$, which is a straight line.

You should be able to sketch the graphs of these two, you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7By%3Dx%5E2-16,3y-16x-16%3D0,y%3D0%7D) to check.

For a good sketch and to set up the limits of integration afterwards, you'll need the points of intersection. You can substitute the line into the parabola or, using $\color{blue}{3y=16x+16}$, start with:
$$y=x^2-16 \implies \color{blue}{3y} = 3x^2-48$$
and so you avoid fractions for a while:
$$\color{blue}{16x+16}=3x^2-48 \iff \ldots \iff x = \ldots$$

Once you have that, you can set up the limits of integration based on your sketch.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I am confused as to how you got 16x+16

Comment: If $3y-16x-16=0$, then (adding $16x+16$ to both sides of the equation), you also have $3y=16x+16$. Or to put it symbolically, if $a-b=0$, then $a=b$; right...?

Comment: I understand now, thank you